# Footable - issues with adding a form in column heading

Tags: javascript, css-position, footable

We have added footable to a complex table. The main aspects are working as desired. However, we have a form inside one of the column headings with a check box that causes all the checkboxes in the column to be toggled. Footable prevents this checkbox in the form in the table heading row from working.

We tried two approaches:

1. Look for a way to enable the form to work within footable. This would be something similar to adding data-type="html" to allow html in the column. However, that does not work. We have not found a way to make the form work; however, this would be the preferred approach, if it is possible.
2. Move the form out of the table, and place it in the desired column heading using absolute positioning. However, under responsive conditions, the absolute positioning fails, as the relatively positioned parent is now outside the table, and it is hard to control the positioning.

You can view a development version of the page by following these instructions:

1. Go to https://qa.rephunter.net
2. Click login in the upper right
3. Member ID: 2322
4. Password: changemenow
5. Click "Manage Contacts"
6. Click "Track Contacts"

At the left of the page you will see the the Archive column heading with the small form. I have attached a screen shot showing a part of the page, and with the checkbox in the heading checked. The proper function would be to check all the checkboxes in the column, which you can see are not checked.

[image]

As I am writing this, it occurs to me that perhaps the checkbox would work without the form; may explore that next.

Answer (score 0):

We have discovered a proximal cause of the problem, and a workaround.

Proximal cause: footable while supporting forms inside cells of rows of the table, does not support having controls with a bound onclick javascript function in a header row. We have not confirmed this limitation nor discovered the root cause, but the described limitation seems reasonable.

Workaround: instead of putting the form in the header row, put it outside the table entirely, and use absolute positioning to make it appear to be in the header cell.

We have applied this method on the page referenced in this question and it works as desired. Because the issue is now solved for us, we have changed the temporary password given above and the page will no longer be accessible to the public.